# Android Studio Admob Error Attribute Unknown

Tags: android, android-studio, ads

I encounter an error while putting the ad banner like the one below
[The Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLXpu.png)

Sorry, it says you need 10 or more reputation to post a picture.

My XML code for ads just like below

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

it is said that I must put code:
`ads:adSize`
in there, but every time I put `ads:adSize` it turns into red and becoming an
error: Attribute Unknown.

do I miss something about in installation?

What could I do so that error won't happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need an attribute like `ads:adSize="BANNER"`

You can add in your code using this:

```
final AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
adView.setAdUnitId("YourId");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```

Comment: Yes, I try to use that but it is resulting an error "error: Attribute Unknown" did I miss something in installation?